# are validation annotations deprecated in strut2?

Tags: validation, struts2, annotations, interceptor, convention

I read from here

https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/annotations.html

that  Annotation are deprecated and changed by Conventions plugin.

I noted that documentation that Convention plugin still use  @Actions or @Interceptor  anottations but they use validation interceptor instead to use  @Validations.

So, should I forget to use @Validation and use validation interceptor?

Answer (score 2):

No, validation annotations are not deprecated. Looking at the API would tell you that.

The comment is specifically in the [Action Annotations section of that page](https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/annotations.html#Annotations-ActionAnnotations), and applies *only* to those annotations, which are now supplied by the convention plugin–as stated.

The validation interceptor is used regardless of validation configuration method.

Comment: Thanks you, Dave. I wouldn't like to change it all to XML Validation Style. However, I have noted that XML Validation style could clean my Action code, but probably I change it in another instance.

Comment: @molavec If the post answers your question, mark it so as to help other SO users.